# Type constrain on generic

Tags: typescript

Unsure if this is a common occurrence, but the code has been functioning without issue thus far. However, TypeScript is raising a complaint regarding the line `to: message.user.email,` and specifically generating the warning message `Unsafe assignment of an any value`. Not sure if I am doing something wrong. Let me know what is going on.

```
const sendWelcomeEmaill = async <T>(message: T) => {
  try {
    const result = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: `"⚡ Magic NextAuth" ${env.EMAIL_FROM}`,
      to: message.user.email,
      subject: 'Welcome to Magic NextAuth! ',
      html: `<div>HELLO</div>`
    }
    );
    const failed = result.rejected.concat(result.pending).filter(Boolean);
    if (failed.length) {
      throw new Error(`Email(s) (${failed.join(", ")}) could not be sent`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

then I call the above function upon `User` creation in the database. The `events` is provided by `next-auth` package.

```
    events: {
        createUser: async (message) => {
          await sendWelcomeEmail<typeof message>(message)
          // typeof message is equal to {user: User}
        },
      },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `message` is a generics and you did not apply any constraint on `T` which mean message may be of any type. Thus trying to access `message.user.email` is unsafe.

Technically your typing would allow

```
sendWelcomeEmail<string>('hello')
```

Which would crash at runtime

You can add constraint to your generic using the `extends` keyword

```
const sendWelcomeEmaill = async <T extends { user: { email: string } }>(message: T) => {
  ...
}
```

But in your case there does not seems be to be any benefit of using generics.
I would simply do

```
const sendWelcomeEmaill = async (message: { user: { email: string } }) => {
  ...
}
```

Or maybe something less specific

```
const sendWelcomeEmaill = async (email: string) => {
  ...
}
```